# Customized France number format

Tags: java

I try to have customized number format for US country. It works fine so far.

```
    // Not something I want.
    NumberFormat numberFormat0 = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.US);        
    System.out.println("US = " + numberFormat0.format(1234.0) + " (I wish to have 1,234.00)");
    System.out.println("US = " + numberFormat0.format(1234.567) + " (I wish to have 1,234.567)");
    System.out.println("US = " + numberFormat0.format(1234.5678) + " (I wish to have 1,234.568)\n");

    // Yes. Something I want :)
    NumberFormat goodNumberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00#");
    System.out.println("US = " + goodNumberFormat.format(1234.0) + " (I wish to have 1,234.00)");
    System.out.println("US = " + goodNumberFormat.format(1234.567) + " (I wish to have 1,234.567)");
    System.out.println("US = " + goodNumberFormat.format(1234.5678) + " (I wish to have 1,234.568)\n");
```

Here is the output.

```
US = 1,234 (I wish to have 1,234.00)
US = 1,234.567 (I wish to have 1,234.567)
US = 1,234.568 (I wish to have 1,234.568)

US = 1,234.00 (I wish to have 1,234.00)
US = 1,234.567 (I wish to have 1,234.567)
US = 1,234.568 (I wish to have 1,234.568)
```

However, same things doesn't work well for France. As they are using `,` for `.`, and "space" for `,`.

I write the following code.

```
    // Not something I want.
    NumberFormat numberFormat1 = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance(Locale.FRANCE);        
    System.out.println("FRANCE = " + numberFormat1.format(1234.0) + " (I wish to have 1 234,00)");
    System.out.println("FRANCE = " + numberFormat1.format(1234.567) + " (I wish to have 1 234,567)");
    System.out.println("FRANCE = " + numberFormat1.format(1234.5678) + " (I wish to have 1 234,567)\n");

    // Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed pattern "# ##0,00#"
    NumberFormat goodNumberFormat1 = new DecimalFormat("# ##0,00#");
    System.out.println("FRANCE = " + goodNumberFormat1.format(1234.0) + " (I wish to have 1 234,00)");
    System.out.println("FRANCE = " + goodNumberFormat1.format(1234.567) + " (I wish to have 1 234,567)");
    System.out.println("FRANCE = " + goodNumberFormat1.format(1234.5678) + " (I wish to have 1 234,567)\n");
```

I am getting the following error.

```
FRANCE = 1 234 (I wish to have 1 234,00)
FRANCE = 1 234,567 (I wish to have 1 234,567)
FRANCE = 1 234,568 (I wish to have 1 234,567)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed pattern "# ##0,00#"
```

Is there anything I can do, to have the above customized number format?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
    DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.FRANCE);
    NumberFormat goodNumberFormat = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00#", dfs);
```

Comment: Oh. I am looking for have "space" as thousands separator. Anyway, your proposed solution is very good :)

Comment: But I am curious. If german or french people need to key in "one point 2", do they type "1,2" or "1.2" in text field? Will Integer.parseInt know how to handle "1,2"?

Comment: Sorry. I mean,  Double.parseDouble

Comment: @Yan Cheng CHEOK: Double.parseDouble uses the internal language format, with decimal point, no thousand separators (like Double.toString).

Comment: I don't understand this solution. He said he doesn't want to specify a country. And why use Germany if you need France?

Comment: @Tudor, I had modifed the author's solution from GERMANY to FRANCE. The solution proposed by auhtor is near to correct.

Answer (score 2):

Taddaaa!

```
DecimalFormatSymbols symbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols();
symbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
symbols.setGroupingSeparator(' ');
NumberFormat goodNumberFormat1 = new DecimalFormat("#,##0.00#", symbols);
System.out.println("FRANCE = " + goodNumberFormat1.format(1234.0) + " (I wish to have 1 234,00)");
System.out.println("FRANCE = " + goodNumberFormat1.format(1234.567) + " (I wish to have 1 234,567)");
System.out.println("FRANCE = " + goodNumberFormat1.format(1234.5678) + " (I wish to have 1 234,567)\n");
```