# Parse BRL currency value String to double

Tags: java, string, parsing, format, currency

I'm trying to parse the following string: "59000,00"

In Brazil, the comma is used to represent decimal places, and the point is used as a symbol to separate the thousands.

What I'm trying to do:

```
final String price = "59000,00";
// LocaleUtils.getLocale returns new Locale("pt", "BR")
final NumberFormat numberFormat = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(LocaleUtils.getLocale());

try {
  final double d = numberFormat.parse(price).doubleValue();
  // do stuff
} catch (ParseException e) {
  // do stuff
}
```

However, I am getting a ParseException. Why would that be?

`java.text.ParseException: Unparseable number: "59000,00" (at offset 8)`

Comment: And your code does not return the expected output, throws an exception, does something else? You did not ask a question.

Comment: @luk2302 D'oh! I'm getting an exception, forgot to mention this in the question! Edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use GERMANY Locale as it uses comma as decimal separator as said [here in the documentation](http://www.oracle.com/us/technologies/java/locale-140624.html). Like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
double df = nf.parse(price).doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

This unit test works for me in **Java 8** but fails in **Java 11-15**.

```java
@Test
public void testBrazilianReal() throws ParseException {
     // Arrange
     Locale brazil = new Locale("pt", "BR");
     DecimalFormat format = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getCurrencyInstance(brazil);
     Double expected = Double.parseDouble("1234.56");
     ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);

     // Act
     Number result = format.parse("R$ 1.234,56", pos);

     // Assert
     assertEquals(expected, result, "Brazil locale");
}
```

In **Java 11** the above test fails with...

```
org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Brazil locale ==> expected: <1234.56> but was: <null>
    at org.junit.jupiter.api.AssertionUtils.fail(AssertionUtils.java:55)
```

**Updated:** Got to the bottom of the problem. In JDK11+ they changed `R$\00A0` as the positivePrefix, where `\00A0` is `&nbsp;` instead of a real space character.

See: [Java Decimal Format parsing issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34156585/java-decimal-format-parsing-issue)

Comment: I had to make an replace from the two kinds of space. Thanks a lot.